# Rewrite directory to parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a bespoke application which require it to be more SEO friendly.

In short, I need to be able to rewrite but `NOT` redirect a URL from something like:

`https://test.com/car/ford/` to something like `https://test.com/car.php?make=ford`

I also need to account for a second parameter such as `https://test.com/car/ford/mustang` which should be rewritten to `https://test.com/car.php?make=ford&model=mustang`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond $0 ^car/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ car/?make=$1 [L]

RewriteCond $0 ^car/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ car/?make=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

I'm not sure if I am tackling this the correct way or if I should be creating a map of some sort.

I would be appreciative if somebody could shed some light as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

does this work for you?

```
RewriteRule ^car/(.*)/$ /car.php?make=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^car/(.*)/(.*)$ /car.php?make=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The first one works, however the second one isn't sending the 2nd directory into the model parameter, i'm thinking its due to the slash in between possibly?